# Processing multiple selections(from a drop down menu) in php and querying database

Tags: php, mysql, database, multipleselection

I am doing multiple selections from a dropdown input form. So, for example: select multiple values 1,2,3,4,5,6. These are IDs from a list of 50 IDs.

My database table has 2 columns - ID and value.

Now, my goal is to write php script with sql query that would take these input IDs(provided by the input form) and return the ID with MAXIMUM value.

I can do it when I know the input IDs. 
For example the sql query would be :`select id, value from tablename where value= (select MAX(value) from tablename where id IN (1,2,3,4));`

However I am unable to find a way, how to handle this situation when I have multiple selections which can vary (since they are coming from an input form).

Should I handle it in the php or SQL? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When posting your form, your multiselect will be sent as an array. Use the `implode(glue, array)` function and then insert the resulting string into your query.